# force update offscreen UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uikit, uicollectionview

I have two view controllers A and B.  ViewControllerA has a UICollectionView on it.

If I push ViewControllerB onto ViewControllerA, then in the background ViewControllerA's UICollectionView updates I want to force the collection view to redraw and dequeue it's cells so that when I return from ViewControllerB ViewControllerA's data is up to date and correct.  Calling reloadData doesnt make the collection view redraw it's self if its in the background, it will wait until after viewWillAppear to trigger 
`[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes]`, which is the method that calls into the datasource to dequeue new cells.

Anyway to force or trick the collectionview so that it calls `[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes]` on new cells prior to viewWillAppear being called?

I am trying to get a custom view controller transition to work and it looks weird if the data has changed in ViewControllerA while looking at ViewControllerB.  I want to force the collectionView to update so when I call CollectionView.visibileIndexPaths the correct items are returned and my animation will look correct.

Comment: You can use delegate to update view of another controllers. Try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling layoutIfNeeded on ViewControllerA's view prior to animating to it again forces the collectionView to update prior to ViewControllerA coming back onscreen.